# Running Python script via systemd fails to load module

Tags: python, linux, service, systemd

I have a Python script that uses `zmq` and I've installed this library via `pip install zmq` and I can run the program fine if called manually via the command line. However as soon as I attempt to have a `systemd` unit call the script, running `systemctl status myservice.service` shows `ImportError: No module named zmq`.

My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Does Something

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh /var/lib/project/runpythonscript.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
Alias=myservice.service
```

Where `runpythonscript.sh` is a very simple shell script that runs my python script as root. Running this shell script manually from the command line runs my python program completely fine but having the service call it causes it to not locate the `zmq` module.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`systemd` runs as root. The modules installed via `pip` are installed for a user rather than for the system and so installing the modules without root privileges made the modules unaccessible for root.

To solve this I ran `sudo -H pip install zmq` and `sudo -H pip3 install zmq` to install the packages for both Python 2.7 and Python 3+ for root. This allowed `systemd` to access the modules once it attempts to execute the Python script.

Comment: Or use `User=<pip_user>` in your unitfile to have your python run as that user. Your python shouldn't run as root unless it needs to.

Answer (score 16):

Add this property to `[Service]` section to make sure `systemd` run as the specified user.

```
User=pi
```

Refer to the solution of [AndyD](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=130982).

Comment: This is by far the quickest and best solution I have found for this issue!

Comment: This is the most efficient and safe way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation is that you have some environment variables set (e.g. an extension of your PYTHONPATH?) which is not set when the script is being run by systemd.

You could try using the Environment parameter (see [0]) so set PYTHONPATH (and whatever else might influence this) to whatever it is in your console session.

[0] http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=

Comment: Thank you! This answer has finally helped me get my project to work after hours of searching for answers that didn't.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I set "EnvironmentFile=" to the user .bash_profile. The issue was that in .bash_profile I had something like:

```
export PYTHONPATH=....
export PATH=....
```

This did not worked with systemd and I had to changed it to:

```
PYTHONPATH=....
PATH=....
export PYTHONPATH PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with similar behavior, but not exactly the same cause. I am replying here anyway in case somebody else runs into it.

My issue was that I tried to launch the script directly (BAD)

```
ExecStart=/var/lib/project/runpythonscript.sh
```

Instead of via /bin/sh (GOOD)

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh /var/lib/project/runpythonscript.sh
```

My original way actually worked for many other scripts that just did various things. But when the shell script file ran Python it failed.